# Mutating the shopping cart using redux-saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js, redux-saga

I am trying to implement a shopping cart using redux-saga. The following code is working fine. But it does not look right to me. I am mutating the cart whenever I am adding the product. Let me know if I can improve the code. If this is the case.

```
import { takeEvery, put } from 'redux-saga/effects';
import * as actions from '../action/saga.js';

function* cart(action) {
  const { product, onSuccess, onError } = action.payload;
  let cart = [];
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
      cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
    }
    const duplicate = cart.find(
      (item) => item._id === product._id
     );
    if (!duplicate) {
      cart.push({
        ...product,
        count: 1,
      });
    } else {
      cart = cart.map((item) =>
        item._id === product._id ? { ...item, count: item.count + 1 } : item
      );
    }
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
  }
  try {
    if (onSuccess)
      yield put({
        type: onSuccess,
        payload: { cart: cart },
      });
  } catch (error) {
    if (onError) yield put({ type: onError, payload: error.message });
  }
}

export function* watchCart() {
  yield takeEvery(actions.sagaCartCallBegan.type, cart);
}
```

Comment: What's your question? Do you need a code review?

Comment: @brc-dd good point!

Comment: @slideshowp2 yes, code review would be fine!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!duplicate) {
  const newCart = [{ ...cart, product, count: 1 }];
} else {
```

...

Then just use newCart:

```
 localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(newCart));
```

...

```
payload: { card: newCart },
```